# MySql grouping returns incorrect result

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay i am attempting to do some SQL magic but sadly it doesnt work as expected. i have the following query:

```
    select 
    `U`.`id` AS `user_id`,
    `athm`.`academy_module_id` AS `module_id`,
    `AHAT`.`academy_team_id` AS `team_id`,
    (case
        when
            ((`act`.`module_id` = `athm`.`academy_module_id`)
                and (`act`.`team_id` = `athm`.`academy_team_id`))
        then
            1
        else 0
    end) AS `is_complete`
from
    (((`user` `U`
    join `user_has_academy_team` `AHAT` ON ((`AHAT`.`user_id` = `U`.`id`)))
    join `academy_team_has_academy_module` `athm` ON ((`AHAT`.`academy_team_id` = `athm`.`academy_team_id`)))
    left outer join `academy_attempt` `act` ON ((`act`.`module_id` = `athm`.`academy_module_id`)))
```

Now without any grouping this returns the following result:

```
user_id, module_id, team_id, is_complete
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '12', '30', '1'
'1', '12', '30', '1'
'1', '12', '30', '1'
'1', '12', '30', '1'
'1', '5', '32', '0'
'1', '10', '32', '0'
'1', '12', '32', '0'
'1', '12', '32', '0'
'1', '12', '32', '0'
'1', '12', '32', '0'
'3', '5', '32', '0'
'3', '10', '32', '0'
'3', '12', '32', '0'
'3', '12', '32', '0'
'3', '12', '32', '0'
'3', '12', '32', '0'
'4', '5', '32', '0'
'4', '10', '32', '0'
'4', '12', '32', '0'
'4', '12', '32', '0'
'4', '12', '32', '0'
'4', '12', '32', '0'
```

Let me explain my goal here:

When a so called module has been taking by my users in my application an attempt will be added into my `academy_attempt`. however a user may take a module several times i.e adding more rows to the `academy_attempt` table. (as you can see user 1 has taken some of the modules several times).

My Goal is to find out which modules has been taking and which modules has not been taking.

Sadly when i group on `academy_module_id` i get the following result:

```
user_id, module_id, team_id, is_complete
'1', '5', '32', '0'
'1', '10', '32', '0'
'1', '11', '30', '1'
'1', '12', '30', '1'
```

I am guessing it is because of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` since the other users does not have a record in`academy_attempt` the result will not be shown.

My question is, is there a work around when working with NULL data?

Here are my table stuctures:

```
Table: user_has_academy_team
Columns:
user_id int(11) PK
academy_team_id int(11) PK
```

---

```
    Table: academy_team_has_academy_module
Columns:
academy_team_id int(11) PK
academy_id  int(11) PK
academy_module_id   int(11) PK
```

---

```
    Table: academy_attempt
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
user_id int(11)
academy_id  int(11)
module_id   int(11)
module_type_id  int(11)
team_id int(11)
score   int(11)
medal_id    int(11) PK
timestamp   datetime
possible_correct    int(11)
user_correct    int(11)
```

---

```
    Table: user
Columns:
id  int(11) AI PK
username    varchar(100)
password    varchar(100)
is_active   int(11)
user_type_id    int(11)
token   varchar(445)
organization_id int(11)
title_id    int(11)
image_path  varchar(100)
division_id int(11)
```

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: `group by academy_module_id, is_complete`? msyql choses arbitrary values for fields that aren't present in the `group by`, or used in an aggregate function

Comment: Can you edit with the raw data from the tables (not just your results from your existing query) and also your expected results? If i understand correctly the ones you posted are your incorrect results, so what are you expecting to see? If you can build an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) it would be really helpful to try and recreate the query.